# Detecting html video fullscreen button when click on it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I have a question maybe it is easy. Is there any way to video control button for detecting. In my project , I want to detect full screen button. If I catch this event, I will set any state. Thanks your answers from now.

```
   <video 
        autoPlay={false}
        onClick={() => {}}
        loop={true} controls={true} muted={false}>
        <source src={"www.example.com"} type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fullscreenchange` event for this.

```
    <video id="video" controls muted="false">
      <source
        src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
      />
    </video>
```

```
function onFullScreen(e) {
  var isFullscreenNow = document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null;
  console.log("Fullscreen event fired " + isFullscreenNow);
}

document
  .getElementById("video")
  .addEventListener("fullscreenchange", onFullScreen);
```

Comment: I tried that. It did not work.

Comment: can you share the code that you tried ? Here's the [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-neumann-4qc57f) of above code.